# Getting the buy price amount and only the buy price amount from Coinbase API

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, coinbase-api

I am messing around with Coinbase's API using Python. When trying to print out the buy price for BTC, I write:

```
client.get_buy_price()
```

Which is great, but it returns:

"amount": "7272.19",
"base": "BTC",
"currency": "USD"

Is there anyway that I can just get the amount only (7272.19)?

Comment: Does it return an object or a string ? 
If it's an object your would just do `client.get_buy_price().amount`

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Great, do you mind accepting the answer i just created ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered in the comments because i was unsure if it returned an object or a string.

Getting it like it was an object worked for the thread starter.

So the correct answer to the question was to get it like `client.get_buy_price().amount`